# how to add a tab into lync 2010 client

Tags: plugins, lync-2010

Thanks First.
Could any one tell me some reference urls or docs to implement this function.

Add a customerized winform tab into lync 2010 client.

(in the main window, not the contact window extension.)

[image: question image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to do this unfortunately. Previous versions of Lync (actually, Office Communicator) let you add custom UI similar to what you are describing, but this functionality has been removed in Lync.

This document (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg398300.aspx) suggests you can add custom tabs using the -TabUrl parameter, but actually this is an error in the documentation, as the Lync client does not support it.

Comment: More information here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ocsmanagement/thread/91188968-4be3-4b01-b1fd-48a2f0da0cef/